# Apply fulltext index on existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have applied the full-text index on two fields (title, description) of an existing table. This table already have 7000 - 8000 records.

The search is not working as expected. Even i provide the full title in the search field but i could not get that record at the top and there are also some non-relevant records.

Is there any need to re-insert all the records in the table after adding the full text index?
Or what could be the problem?

Here is the query for reference:

```
SELECT * FROM f_table f WHERE MATCH (f.tit, f.des) AGAINST ('Rasta Man Vocal 4')
```

Its not showing this 'Rasta Man Vocal 4' record at the top. Its it on the 4th position. 
Here is the detail of first four records:

```
#  (tit)                (des)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) Rasta Vocal 1.wav    Male Rasta Vocal-Tune into the King
2) Rasta Jah DnB        Rasta Increase Come from Jah DnB Vocal Reggae
3) Rasta Man Vocal 2    Rasta Man Vocal 2 Download
4) Rasta Man Vocal 4    Rasta Man Vocal 4 Download
```

Its just an example.

Please help, thanks in advance...

Another question: Is there a way to give more preference to one field (tit) than other (des)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT *,MATCH (f.tit, f.des) AGAINST ('Rasta Man Vocal 4') as relevance  FROM f_table f WHERE MATCH (f.tit, f.des) AGAINST ('Rasta Man Vocal 4') order by relevance desc
```